# Java GUI Reading a file with the mentioned path

Tags: java, swing, io, filereader, file-search

```
JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                try{                
                    String filename =  fileName.getText();
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(br);
                     filename = br.readLine();

                    if (filename != null){

                  String text = txtKeyword.getText();  
                  String line;
                  boolean hasError = true;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if(line.contains(text)){
                    String newline = "\n";
                    jTextArea1.append(line + newline);
                    hasError = false;
                }   
                }
                if (hasError) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text Not Found");
                       br.close();
                       fr.close();
                    } 
                }}catch(IOException e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found");
            }   }   
        });
```

So, in this function, I want to read some text files within a mentioned directory/folder by input. User selects the directories/folder using JFILECHOOSER method and the output will be listed in a textbox [Directory]. Lets say that fileName is the text field where users input the name of the file, after users input their file name, they click on a start button. The start button functions on whereby it will look into the given directory/folder [the textbox] and search for text files and output the text files' name using system.out.printIn. I have not tried the code for directory/folder path because I'm not sure how to code for it. Any help or guide to this problem? I have only created one class and I'm new to JAVA GUI

The full code is as below:

```
package com.directory.file;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.TextComponent;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;

public class Directory extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtKeyword;
    private JTextField fileName;
    private JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private JDateChooser dateChooser;
    private JSpinner spinner_1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Directory frame = new Directory();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setSize(450,630);
                    frame.fileName.requestFocus(); 
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();        
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Directory() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 436, 631);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDirectory = new JLabel("Directory:");
        lblDirectory.setBounds(20, 29, 55, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblDirectory);

        JLabel lblDate = new JLabel("Date:");
        lblDate.setBounds(37, 141, 55, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblDate);

        txtKeyword = new JTextField();
        txtKeyword.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtKeyword.setToolTipText("");
        txtKeyword.setColumns(10);
        txtKeyword.setBounds(85, 193, 229, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtKeyword);

        final JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
        dateChooser.setDateFormatString("YYYMMd");
        dateChooser.setBounds(85, 141, 229, 20);
        contentPane.add(dateChooser);

        JLabel lblKeyword = new JLabel("Keyword:");
        lblKeyword.setBounds(20, 191, 55, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblKeyword);

        JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
        separator.setBounds(148, 204, -113, 34);
        contentPane.add(separator);

        JButton btnExport = new JButton("Export");
        btnExport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     
            }
        });
        btnExport.setBounds(324, 556, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnExport);

        final JLabel Directory = new JLabel("");
        Directory.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        Directory.setBounds(85, 30, 290, 22);
        contentPane.add(Directory);

        int min = 0;
        int max = 23;
        int step = 1;
        int initValue = 0;
        SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(initValue, min, max, step);
        final JSpinner spinner_1 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 23-1, 1));

        spinner_1.setBounds(324, 143, 89, 20);
                contentPane.add(spinner_1);


        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("...");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                String filename =f.getAbsolutePath();
                Directory.setText(filename);

        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(377, 30, 36, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

        final JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
        jTextArea1.setRows(15);
        jTextArea1.setColumns(15);
        jTextArea1.setBounds(42, 249, 351, 294);
        jTextArea1.setLineWrap(true);
        jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        contentPane.add(jTextArea1);
        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                try{                
                    String filename =  fileName.getText();
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(br);
                     filename = br.readLine();

                    if (filename != null){

                  String text = txtKeyword.getText();  
                  String line;
                  boolean hasError = true;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if(line.contains(text)){
                    String newline = "\n";
                    jTextArea1.append(line + newline);
                    hasError = false;
                }   
                }
                if (hasError) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text Not Found");
                       br.close();
                       fr.close();
                    } 
                }}catch(IOException e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found");
            }   }
        });

        btnStart.setBounds(324, 215, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnStart);


        JLabel lblFileName_1 = new JLabel("File Name:");
        lblFileName_1.setBounds(20, 79, 75, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblFileName_1);


        fileName = new JTextField();
        fileName.setToolTipText("");
        fileName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        fileName.setColumns(10);
        fileName.setBounds(85, 81, 290, 20);
        contentPane.add(fileName);
        contentPane.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{fileName, lblDirectory, lblDate, txtKeyword, btnStart, lblKeyword, separator, btnExport, Directory, dateChooser, dateChooser.getCalendarButton(), spinner_1, btnNewButton, jTextArea1, lblFileName_1}));          
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't use `null` layouts. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen. Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...

Comment: Why have a seperate field for the directory and file?  Why not use the `JFileChooser` to select the file you want to read as a single step?

Comment: It works like I search for directory. And the directory is fixed. Then I input the file name and press the start button, the result will pop up the file name.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem #1

You only ever use the `fileName` value when trying to open the file...

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
```

A file is a catenation of the directory and the name, for example...

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(Directory.getText(), filename));
```

#### Problem #2

You're doing some kind of pre-emptive read on the file which is not required...

```
if (filename != null){

    String text = txtKeyword.getText();  
    String line;
    boolean hasError = true;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

You should just start reading the file, otherwise you've lost the first line of text

#### Problem #3

You're not closing the streams in the event of some kind of exception...

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(Directory.getText(), filename));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    //...
} catch (IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found");
}
```

If, for some reason, an exception occurs while you are opening or reading the streams, they can never be closed...at least not until the JVM closes

Instead, you should either be using `try-with-resources` if you're using Java 7+ or a `finally` block to ensure the streams are closed, for example...

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    String filename = fileName.getText();
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(Directory.getText(), filename)));
    //...
} catch (IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found");
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

It would also be of more help to you if you at least dumped the stack trace of the actual exception or logged it some how...

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found");
} finally {
```

#### Problem #4

`null` layout.  Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen.

Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...